# Staggering labels or adding only selected labels on ggplot stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am plotting a series of Likert scale questions as stacked bar charts. They need to be labelled but some of the segments are two small and get overlaps like the example below (with sample code below it). Is there a clever way to either only label sections that are big enough to fit the label or a way to stagger how the labels are presented?

[image]

```
q1a<-rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c(2, 5,45,45))
q1b<-rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c(45,45,2, 5))
data<-data.frame(q1a,q1b)

data %>%
  select(q1a:q1b) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Question") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  count(Question, value) %>%
  group_by(Question) %>%
  mutate(Pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = value, x = Pct, y = fct_rev(Question))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(sprintf("%1.0f", Pct * 100), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = "Question 1", y = "Question", x = "Percentage") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: You could use `geom_text(aes(label=if_else(Pct > 0.03, paste0(sprintf("%1.0f", Pct*100),"%"), "")), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3) + ` to remove labels below 3%, for instance.

Comment: Or you might add a `arrange(-Pct) %>%` before ggplot, and then put `check_overlap = TRUE` into your geom_text. That will write the text starting from largest values, and skip anything that would overlap prior plotted text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I'll only display labels for `Pct` greater than 5% using `if_else()` in `geom_text(aes())`. If it's less than 5%, display nothing.

Also, since your `geom_bar` position is `fill`, you should also use `position = position_fill()` in `geom_text` to align the position.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  select(q1a:q1b) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Question") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  dplyr::count(Question, value) %>%
  group_by(Question) %>%
  mutate(Pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = value, x = Pct, y = fct_rev(Question))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = if_else(Pct > 0.05, paste0(sprintf("%1.0f", Pct * 100), "%"), NULL)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = "Question 1", y = "Question", x = "Percentage") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image: labelPCT]